# There was an error sending email from "bugzilla-daemon" to "abc@xyz.com": no sender

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, bugzilla

I'd like to research about bugzilla. So I use bugzilla-5.0 to setup my bugzilla in local VM. But When I tried to create a bug or comment something in bugzilla. It noticed that: There was an error sending email from "bugzilla-daemon" to "abc@xyz.com": no sender.

Although I configured mail_delivery_methos is "Sendmail" in Administrator/Email/mail_delivery_method and mailfrom is "bugzilla-daemon". But It was failed.

Does anybody have any idea for that problem?

Comment: Could you post the relevant entries from your MTA/SMTP server log files?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I was wondering if you have solved it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It started working for me when I changed the sender from "bugzilla-daemon" to a fully qualified address (eg bugzilla-daemon@my.domain.com).

Answer (score 6):

Bugzilla 5.0.2 in centos 
Had same issue, but got solved by following steps 

1. locate 'params.json'.
 
In my case @ '/var/www/html/bugzilla/data/params.json'.
2. find and change to,
   "mail_delivery_method" : "SMTP",
   "mailfrom" :"mail-id given while install",
   "maintainer" : "mail-id given while install"

DONE

Answer (score 5):

Through administrator menu, select Parameters, 'Email'. Change input field for'mailfrom' to a valid email-address.

Comment: This is proper way than hacking files.

Answer (score 2):

I have change following and it was successfull make following field blanlk

`'mail_delivery_method' => ''`,

and add (this fileds may be blank initialy)

`'smtp_password' => 'your password'`

`'smtp_username' => 'admin email'`